# Syntax for Functions in Bash

Tags: bash, unix, script

I do know the JavaScript syntax:

var functionName = function(some perameter){

some code here;
};

but what is the syntax for a function in bash?

Comment: You are getting downvoted because you can find an answer to this with 5 minutes worth of web search. In general, questions that can be answered with RTFM get downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to create Bash functions:

```
function function_name { 
  # your commands
}
```

Or:

```
function_name () { 
  # your commands
}
```

Both are equivalent. Read more about it, for example in the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide under [Functions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) or in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions).

Comment: Three ways, technically: `function foo () {` is also allowed. Only one of the keyword `function` and the parentheses are required, though. The `function` keyword is a `bash` extension, though; your second example is the standard way of defining a function and will work in any POSIX-compatible shell.